# I want to fetch last inserted data from database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I created table like this

```
id
a1
a2
a3
a
a4
a5
a6

1
3
1
7
63
3
5
0


2
3
1
7
35
3
5
0

3
3
1
7
40
3
5
0


5
1
5
5
44
2
2
2

6
5
6
9
07
5
5
7

7
5
6
9
07
5
5
7
```

Now I want to fetch latest data from this table to homepage of my website.

Latest row would be max id.

***On home page it should show like this:***

> a1a2a3 - a - a4a5a6

Means

On home page it should show {- is separator}
like this:

I used following code but it prints only a value which is INR of 2

```
<?php

mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");
mysql_select_db(dbname);

$q = "SELECT a FROM table
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1;";
$result = mysql_query($q);
$data = mysql_fetch_array($result);

echo $data[0];

?>
```

Comment: There is no field `a` in your table description but `a1`, `a2`, ...., so what does `SELECT a` really select?

Comment: i create coulm   a1 a2 a3 after that i added a.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you select only a single column `a`? try `CONCAT(col1,col2,...)`

```
$q = "SELECT CONCAT(a1,a2,a3,' - ',a,' - ',a4,a5,a6) FROM result ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1;";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function mysql_insert_id() to get the last auto incrementing Id.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "Select max (id) as theid from table";
$result = Mysqli_query ($link, $query);
$r = mysqli_fetch_object ($result);
Echo $r->theid;
```

Should do it. The mysqli_insert_id function will only work if the most recent query was an insert query which doesn't appear is the case in the question.

Hope that helps.